# Why does PhpMyAdmin put the indexes at the end of a dump?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, phpmyadmin, adminer

When I export a MySQL database with Adminer or with mysqldump, it produces a .sql file with each table definition followed by (if the table is non-empty) an `INSERT` statement (or multiple statements for large tables). The table definition includes indexes and constraints. It will also include the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value if that is different from what you'd get after running the inserts.

By contrast, a PhpMyAdmin export defines the table without any indexes or constraints, and then inserts the data. At the end, after all tables have been created and all data has been inserted, are a bunch of `ALTER TABLE` commands to add keys, then a further set to add `AUTO_INCREMENT` rules, and finally a further set to add constraints.

Why the difference? Both export styles will produce the same database in the end. I assume that PhpMyAdmin made a deliberate, intentional choice to deviate from the mysqldump style. In my subjective experience (I've not actually measured) PhpMyAdmin dumps are slower to run than Adminer or mysqldump dumps. I imagine that they must have some benefit. What?

I might guess that if you're running a PhpMyAdmin dump on an older version of MySQL which doesn't understand constraints (do any such exist?) you will at least have all your data before hitting an error. Perhaps in this sense the PhpMyAdmin dumps are more robust?

Comment: CREATE+INSERT+INDEX is more fast then CREATE+INDEX+INSERT.

Comment: So that means that my subjective impression is wrong?

Comment: Dropping indexes before doing batch inserts is a frequently used strategy to speed up bulk inserts. This is just an example of that. Why don't you do a test on your system and see how it works out for you?

Comment: @Akina - That does not apply to the `PRIMARY KEY` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`, especially when the data to insert is in PK order. CREATE+PRIMARYKEY+INSERT+INDEX may be the best in _most cases_

Comment: @RickJames PRIMARY KEY **must** be created in CREATE TABLE.

Comment: @Akina - Technically, yes, a hidden PK is generated by default.  I'm suggestion that an _explicit_ PK should be included in the `CREATE`.  Note that an `ALTER` that modifies the PK must do `ALGORITHM=COPY`.

Comment: @RickJames I mean this too. If it is not created in CREATE TABLE then further ADD PRIMARY KEY will forbid in-place altering algorithm.

Answer (score -3):

It's possible to modify PHPMYADMIN to put the `PRIMARY KEY` and attributes directly into the `CREATE TABLE` structure. In this example, I'll explain how to do it using a **WAMP server**.

We want to edit the following file, and make two changes:

```
C:\Networking\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin5.0.2\libraries\classes\Plugins \Export\ExportSql.php
```

1. On line 1822 I commented out:

   ```
   // $ create_query = $ statement-> build ();
   ```
2. On line 1720 I commented out:

   ```
   $ alter_header = 'ALTER TABLE' at line 1822 end statement}
   ```

Afterwards I tried export and it works with `PRIMARY KEY` and attributes placed in `CREATE TABLE` structure.

Comment: It seems the authors did this for the speed of execution, however for large data if you don't use -transaction- and -rollback-, imports and exports can be a timeout problem. It may not be best practice to change the code, but it works and is useful.

Comment: I'm mostly asking why PhpMyAdmin does what it does, not really asking how to change it.

Comment: I'm curious to know if this actually works (As of this writing, the reason this has a score of -3 is more likely because of the poor english, but now that it's been edited to be more readable, I'd be interested to know if this actually does anything.)