# phpmyadmin schema dump, how to avoid alter table for key definitions?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I dump the mysql db schema with phpmyadmin (5.2.0), I would like to get something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `MEASURE_TABLE` (
  `measureID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sensorID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`measureID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`sensorID`) REFERENCES `LOGICAL_SENSOR_TABLE` (`sensorID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Instead I get something like this (key defined via "ALTER TABLE"):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MEASURE_TABLE`;
CREATE TABLE `MEASURE_TABLE` (
  `measureID` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sensorID` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

ALTER TABLE `MEASURE_TABLE`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`measureID`),
  ADD KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  ADD KEY `sensorID` (`sensorID`);

ALTER TABLE `MEASURE_TABLE`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `MEASURE_TABLE_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sensorID`) REFERENCES `LOGICAL_SENSOR_TABLE` (`sensorID`);
```

I'm pretty sure they are equivalent, but for me the first version is much more readable.
I had a previous schema dump from phpmyadmin (not done by me), that was in the first format. It was a different version though (4.6.6deb5).

I couldn't find the option in the export menu, is it possible to change it?

Comment: FKs need to be applied in a specific order, hence leaving them until the end.  I do _not_ understand why the PK is not included with the CREATE.

Comment: In this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/254089/why-does-phpmyadmin-put-the-idexes-at-the-end-of-a-dump they say that indexes are added at the end for speeding up the insert (CREATE, INSERT, INDEX), but in this case I have no data. If I select the option to add IF NOT EXIST for table creation, keys are added inside CREATE TABLE. Foreign key constraints are still outside

Answer (score 0):

I, too, wish the dump had the entire table definition in one spot.

To get the entire definition afterwards, do

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename
```

Such is often very helpful in programming questions about MySQL/MariaDB.

Some lame explanations for what you are seeing:

The `PRIMARY KEY` is an index and a uniqueness constraint; in most situations, it would be faster (for `INSERTs`) to have it already declared in the table. `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL` are probably required to be created after loading the data. For other `INDEXes` (including `UNIQUE`), the speed is more debatable; it works either way.

In particular, `ALTERing` the `PRIMARY KEY` always requires copying the table!  Very inefficient.

This forum (and others) are littered with the same question about `FOREIGN KEYs` -- an error message because the referenced table has not been declared before the FK is declared.  The simple fix is to push them to after declaring all tables.

I guess that the tool you are asking about did something simple that made it work, but without thinking about performance.  File a bug report against the tool, if you like.  (and add a link here)

Comment: If you look what `mysqldump`/`mariadb-dump` do, both set `UNIQUE_CHECKS=0,FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` in the beginning of the session and restore this at the end of the dump.

Comment: @danblack - Can you justify all the ALTERs being separate from the CREATE?  (This is one of the mysteries I have not figured out yet.)

Comment: The primary key not being in the original `CREATE` is odd as I'd assume the data is dump in PK order and therefore an insert is going to be really quick. Even if its not, the cost is a possible a little more disk space but will save time. Secondary keys are going to be a more unordered generally so there might be a case for creating secondary indexes once all the data is there. FK constraints, at the same time as secondary or primary would be better than a separate post import, if actual relations are checked, but the cases for doing FK key checks on a complete import are fairly rate.